# Unhandled rejection MongoError with bluebird.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack, bluebird

I have a MEAN stack application and I am trying to create a user. I am using [Bluebird.js](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) as a promise library but I am getting a weird unhandled rejection error although I am catching it.
Here is my code:

`controllers/users.js`

```
module.exports = {
  // create user from a JSON object
  createUser: function(user) {
    var email = user.email;
    var password = user.password;
    if (!password || !email) {
      return Promise.reject(errors.missingInfo);
    }
    // check if the token doesn't exist then add it
    if (!user.token) {
      user.token = uuid.v4();
    }
    if (!user.isActive) {
      user.isActive = true;
    }

    return userModel.createAsync(user).then(function(newUser) {      
      newUser = newUser.toObject();
      delete newUser.password;
      return newUser;
    }).catch(function(/*err*/) {
      throw errors.alreadyUsed;
    });
  }
}
```

`routes/users.js`

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  ctrl.createUser(req.body).then(function(user) {
    res.json(user);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    if (err.error) {
      if (err.status) {
        res.status(err.status);
      }
      else {
        res.status(500);
      }
      res.json(err);
    }
    else {
      var message = err instanceof Error ? err.message : err;
      res.status(500).json({
        error: message
      });
    }
  });
})
```

So when I am testing the case where I enter an already used username or email the frontend gets the error right but the console of the server prints the following error in red:

```
Unhandled rejection MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: coll.users index: email_1 dup key: { : "email@example.com" }
```

I tried to change the line `throw errors.alreadyUsed;` to `return Promise.reject(errors.alreadyUsed);` but with the same result.

Comment: Looks like everything is fine. You have a duplicated email so you get the error in console

Comment: Thank you @AmiramKorach your comment rang a bell and the reason why I am getting this is because I am telling mongoose to use bluebird promises `mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');` as pointed out in [Mongoose website](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).  
Removing this line prevented the error from being shown in the console